# Monster chase game on a board: why doesn't X appear if user enters 1 on first go?

Tags: python

Essentially this game allows user to choose a space on a 25 space board. There's a monster that randomly chooses a space (work in progress with the user's 'scent').

If you start the program and enter 1 as your first move it doesn't appear on the board. Does anyone know why this may be?

Bonus questions:

- I'd like for the 'scent' to disappear after one turn..any ideas?
  or
- I'd like user to get points for amount of scent left on before dyeing. Any ideas?

```
import random

choice = 0
move = 0
user = "  X  "
monster = "<{:}>"
scent = "  i  "
space = "     "
rabbit = True

mapp = [space for i in range (25)]
print(mapp)


def print_mapp():
    row_1 = "|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(mapp[0],mapp[1],mapp[2],mapp[3],mapp[4])
    row_2 = "|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(mapp[5],mapp[6],mapp[7],mapp[8],mapp[9])
    row_3 = "|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(mapp[10],mapp[11],mapp[12],mapp[13],mapp[14])
    row_4 = "|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(mapp[15],mapp[16],mapp[17],mapp[18],mapp[19])
    row_5 = "|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(mapp[20],mapp[21],mapp[22],mapp[23],mapp[24])

    print()
    print(row_1)
    print(row_2)
    print(row_3)
    print(row_4)
    print(row_5)
    print()

print_mapp()

def user_move():
    global choice
    if user in mapp:
        mapp[choice] = scent
    choice = (int(input("Where would you like to move? (1-25): "))-1)
    check()
    mapp[choice] = user

def monster_move():
    global move
    mapp[move] = space
    move = (random.randint(1,25))-1
    check()
    mapp[move] = monster

def check():
    if  (mapp[choice] == monster) or (mapp[move] == user):
        print("Die sucka\n"*20)
        global rabbit
        rabbit = False
    else:
        pass



while rabbit == True:
    user_move()
    monster_move()
    print_mapp()


print("You died a horrible death.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `monster_move`, specifically the line:

```
mapp[move] = space
```

You initialize `move = 0` at the beginning, so it always erases the first square, and since it happens after the user has moved, the user won't show up there.

Instead, you could set it to a different value for the first round and check against that:

```
move = -1
```

and in `monster_move`:

```
if move > -1:
    mapp[move] = space
```

**Bonus questions:**

> I'd like for the 'scent' to disappear after one turn..any ideas?

Keep track of previous positions and use that to remove the scent. If you use a queue data structure (in Python, this can be done with a `list`), it is easy to extend to "fancier" algorithms like keeping track for more than one turn.

At the top, initialize

```
prev_moves = []
```

And in `user_move`, remove the old scent and add the new:

```
def user_move():
    global choice
    if user in mapp:
        mapp[choice] = scent # replace the user marker
        if len(prev_moves) > 0:
            mapp[prev_moves.pop(0)] = space # remove earliest move
        prev_moves.append(choice) # add most recent move
        print(prev_moves)
    for move in prev_moves: # place scent markers
        mapp[move] = scent
    choice = (int(input("Where would you like to move? (1-25): "))-1)
    check()
    mapp[choice] = user
```

If you wanted scent to last longer, just check how long the list is and only `pop` if it's greater than what you want.

> I'd like user to get points for amount of scent left on before dyeing. Any ideas?

With the list implementation above, you can just check `len(prev_moves)`.